# SQL Server linked server and Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server, high-availability

I have a database within a SQL server 2008 server (Server A, with database A) that requires to communicate (both ways) to another database in a separate SQL server 2014 server (Server B, with database B).

Easy enough, but Server B is part of an AG group, with one secondary replica (Server C).  My question is:

Do I have to create a SQL script (sp_addlinkedserver) on ALL Servers (A, B and C), and the AG listener; or just some of them?  I assume I have to at least create "add linked server" scripts for A & B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a linked server on all three servers otherwise, you will not have the linked server present when the AlwaysOn High Availabilty Group fails over.

On A to the listener for the AG
On B to A
On C to A